# Windows Explorer hangs when deleting files

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Windows Explorer sometimes hangs deleting files. How can this be avoided?

[image]

I use Windows 7.

Answer (score 4):

> **Windows Explorer sometimes hangs deleting files. How to avoid that?**

### To avoid this. . .

Delete the files you need to delete via administrator elevated command prompt with the [DEL](http://ss64.com/nt/del.html) command in order to avoid Windows Explorer from "hanging", etc.

### Why this doesn't occur with command line . . .

<sup>(1)</sup> The delete operation from the command line `DEL` command isn't as prone to memory fragmentation as `Explorer.exe` is since typically when you open command prompt it opens a new instance of `cmd.exe` in memory and starts using it, and then you close it when done.

<sup>(2)</sup> Windows Explorer also has some built in calculation steps so it does some calculations with delete operations for what you're going to delete, how long it may take, and so on, so these features take more time and this too is not applicable with the command line [DEL](http://ss64.com/nt/del.html) command.

---

You may be able to test killing explorer.exe and then opening a new instance of it, and then doing the delete operation from the Windows Explorer GUI to see if that clears up any issues with it being fragmented in memory.

**Kill Explorer and Open a New Instance of it from Command Line**

```
TASKKILL /I /IM "Explorer.exe"
Explorer
```

---

**Command Line DEL Example**

```
DEL /Q /F "C:\Server\ftpmetadata\dm4\features\*.*"
```

*Additionally, you could use PowerShell and use the [Remove-Item](http://ss64.com/ps/remove-item.html) command.*

---

### Further Resources

- [**DEL**](http://ss64.com/nt/del.html)
- [**Remove-Item**](http://ss64.com/ps/remove-item.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is the option of bypassing the recycle bin entirely by using `shift+delete`. Also, increasing your systems paging file could help performance.